# Join or subquery in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, join, ms-access-2007, subquery

I looked at the "Related Questions" as I started this, but none of them are exactly the same as what I'm trying do.

If at all possible, I want my query to be updatable.

Which is better?

```
SELECT foobar.foo, foobar.bar
FROM foobar
WHERE foobar.baz IN (SELECT blahwoof.baz FROM blahwoof WHERE blahwoof.blah = 'value')
```

Or:

```
SELECT foobar.foo, foobar.bar
FROM foobar INNER JOIN blahwoof ON foobar.baz = blahwoof.baz
WHERE blahwoof.blah = 'value'
```

**Edit**

I've fully qualified the column names above. I also realized that I hadn't fully specified that it's only `foobar` that I care about updating--`blahwoof` is a lookup table only.

**Edit 2**

Bare-bones schema as follows (not actual code, obviously):

```
table foobar
  foo       Autonumber PK
  bar       long       FK ref gleeblesnort
  baz       long       FK ref blahwoof

table blahwoof
  baz       Autonumber PK
  blah      text       --'type' designation
```

I'll eventually be pulling values from gleeblesnort as well, but that's not a direct part of this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of the view will be updateable in any reasonably compliant SQL RDBMS.

Comment: The JOIN version of this specific example should also be updatable. Your point, I'm sure, is that the IN subquery will be updatable more often than the JOIN version, particular if the query optimizer can't determine exactly how many records are returned by the JOIN statement.

Comment: @David, to be honest, I originally had a second paragraph explaining how and why to make this view updateable in Access.  But I discovered I was wrong (I somehow had gotten the idea it required DISTINCTROW), so I took it out and left the first paragraph.

Comment: DISTINCTROW can make some SELECT statements editable that are read-only without it, but it's not easy to predict when it will work and when it won't. It depends entirely on the cause of the non-editability. Basically, if the problem is one of Jet being unable to figure out how many rows there are on each side of the join, DISTINCTROW will very often be able to make it editable (though not always). However, if the cause of non-editability is due to domain aggregates or GROUP BY in one of the JOINed SELECTs, DISTINCTROW will have not effect.

Comment: Accepted because I've gone with the subquery, even though there doesn't seemto be a firm consensus of the answers either way. Testing showed each to work, with no detectable performance difference in my (admittedly small) sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inner join.  It should be much more performant.  IIRC, this will be updatable, too.

Comment: The answer depends on the SQL statement. If the JOIN version is updatable, it will likely be faster. If it's not and you need updatability, then the IN subquery is the better version. But that's really only relevant to a bound Access form (where it's VERY relevant) or when walking and editing a recordset.

Comment: It is going to be on a bound form, but--as I said in my edit--it's really only `foobar.bar` that needs to be updatable.

Comment: I think my answer was a little hasty, as @David has got me thinking.  It would be good to know a bit more about the schema - PKs, FKs, Unique Indexes...the inner join could return the foobar row more than once, where blahwoof.baz is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not the same query. in the first query if you have 1 baz value it is enough to satisfy the WHERE condition, and you actually meant for the join results (baz and blah=value...)

(you might need to use table prefix infornt of baz to make it clearer)

Comment: There's a `baz` in each table, and several rows of it in `blahwoof`. It's the only column thay have in common. See edit.